# Single Ruby Value in One Line From a Collection

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have a collection of objects. There are 3 properties in each object

'id', 'name', 'is_primary'

The collection of objects will usually have anywhere from 1 to 5 objects.

What I want to do is check the collection to see if is_primary is true. If so output the name, or at least return it.

I want to do this in 1 line of code if possible. I am trying to slim up this one line for erb output in rails. Later in the page i'll output them all. I thought I had it, but if I return nil it adds extra space which shifts all the html oddly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, this doesn't quite work if no element `is_primary`...I'm still thinking...

```
c.detect(&:is_primary).name
```

Ok, how about:

```
((a = c.detect(&:is_primary)) && a.name).to_s
```

As it happens, it is OK in an erb template for the `<%=` expression to return `nil`, that just results in an empty string, so for that case you can use:

```
(a = c.detect(&:is_primary)) && a.name
```

*Update:* Responding to the first comment, I do have a test case that I didn't post...

```
class A; attr_accessor :is_primary, :name, :id; end
t = [A.new, A.new, A.new, (a = A.new; a.name = 'xyz'; a.is_primary = true; a)]

puts (a = t.detect(&:is_primary)) && a.name

puts ((a = [].detect(&:is_primary)) && a.name).to_s
```

Comment: hmmm, I have tried each of those options and keep getting the name of the object instead of the name property in the object.

Comment: I have absolutely now idea what i did different, but now it is working. Thank you. Also where can I read about what that code does? that is an awesome line, but don't know really how to read it so i can do it myself in the future. thanks again.

Comment: For the future, you might find it faster to write `A = Struct.new( :is_primary, :name, :id )`; it's also then easier to write `[A.new, A.new( true, 'xyz' )]`

Comment: @percent20, your bible will be http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/  The hardest thing to look up is the `&:sym` expression, but the secret is that `class Symbol` has a `to_proc` method, so the method `is_primary` will be called because `&` will convert the proc to a block. Also be sure to check `class Enumerable`, where you will find lots of things that work with collections.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @DigitalRoss, you can also write:

```
collection.detect(&:is_primary).try(:name) || "default_if_no_element_or_name"
```

(well, to be honest I prefer Ick's *maybe* over Rails' *try*: `c.detect(&:is_primary).maybe.name`)

Side note: IMHO a flag that can only be active for a row it's not such a good idea. You may have inconsistent states with more than one being active and you'll have worry about it when updating (transactions, and so on). Try to store the PK reference somewhere else (a parent model? a state model?).

*I want to do this in 1 line of code if possible. I am trying to slim up this one line for erb output in rails. Later in the page i'll output them all.*

No need for one-liners (funny since I just wrote one): move the code to yous models or helpers as appropriate and keep your views pristine.